# Turn PDU device on with Laravel Scheduler and Laravel Redirect

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, scheduled-tasks

I have a Power Delivery Unit device connected to my local network, that is controlled by a simple web page and I´m trying to use Laravel Schedule to turn the device on and off at specific times of the day. So I´ve created a PDUController with the following methods: (both approaches work fine)

```
public function on()
{
    return redirect()->away(
        "http://192.168.0.100/control_outlet.htm?outlet6=1&outlet7=1&op=0&submit=Apply"
    );
}

public function off()
{
    return Redirect::to(
        "http://192.168.0.100/control_outlet.htm?outlet6=1&outlet7=1&op=1&submit=Apply"
    );
}
```

If you visit the routes:

```
Route::get('/pdu/on', [PDUController::class, 'on'])->name('pdu.on');
Route::get('/pdu/off', [PDUController::class, 'off'])->name('pdu.off');
```

Everything works as expected and you can turn the device on or off accordingly. Now when I use the Scheduler on Kernel.php like:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\PDUController@on')->everyMinute();
}
```

It doesn´t work.
I know the flow is right, because I can Log::debug() every step of the process correctly, but the device is not receiveing the signal and thus is not turning on.
Could you help, please? Thanks!

Comment: The redirects tell a browser to go on to another website, but does not actually generate the connection itself. The scheduler uses Artisan, which does not involve a browser. You might have better luck with the [HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#introduction)

Comment: You´re a master @aynber. Guzzle works like a charm. Could you turn your answer into a proper one, so I can select it as solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redirect functions return a redirect response to the browser. Since the scheduler runs through Artisan, there is no browser to redirect, so no connection is made. Instead, use the [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#introduction) to create a connection to the page.